# For loop for calculating p-value on each row of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, bioinformatics, p-value

I have a subset of triplicates that belong to a Group.
The dataset contains more than 30k rows with information for each triplicates.
I want to perform a Wilcoxon Test on these two Groups.
Before these lines of codes, I have used iloc to get the subset of groups

```
groupA = subset.iloc[:,4:7]
groupB = subset.iloc[:,7:10]
```

I am trying to make a for loop to go over every row and calculate the wilcoxon test on each group:

## #Calculate the pvalue using Wilcoxon test

```
import scipy.stats as stats
from scipy.stats import ranksums


def stats(x):
ranksums(x.groupA, x.groupB)



result[]

for i in range(len(subset)):
row = subset.iloc[i]
result.append(
   stats
)
print(result)
```

The code runs for over 4min and it returns the same values for all rows, which seems incorrect:
#output: [RanksumsResult(statistic=-10.39971253610489, pvalue=2.4868227406906807e-25), RanksumsResult(statistic=-10.39971253610489, pvalue=2.4868227406906807e-25), RanksumsResult(statistic=-10.39971253610489, pvalue=2.4868227406906807e-25)....

**Update**
I am trying to create the groups within the for loop, but it takes longer (9min) and it returns only one answer..

```
my_list = []

for i, row in subset.iterrows():
   groupA = subset.iloc[i,4:7]
   groupB = subset.iloc[i,7:10]
   my_list = ranksums(groupA, groupB)

my_list
```

It returns: RanksumsResult(statistic=array([  7.07673793,  -1.9041147 , -12.48672522]), pvalue=array([1.47587257e-12, 5.68952474e-02, 8.82102979e-36]))
which means is not applying the test over all rows and apparently applying to the group of columns. I wonder if I should create arrays within the for  loop then apply the test, but how can I do this without taking so long

Comment: Hi Maria, welcome to StackOverflow. If possible, can you please edit your 'example' dataset to include more columns? The relevance of "Blank 0µm" / "Nutrient 0µm" are not clear to me based on the example provided.

Comment: Hello @jared_mamrot, I have updated the question, hopefully it makes more sense now